# Counting on the unit cube: avoiding a symmetry argument

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let ${n = 2^m-1}$, and that ${X_j := (-1)^{a_j \cdot Y}}$, where ${Y}$ is drawn uniformly at random from the cube ${\{0,1\}^m}$, and ${a_1,\ldots,a_n}$ are an enumeration of the non-zero elements of ${\{0,1\}^m}$, show that the sum of the $X_j$ is $n$ if $Y=0$ and $-1$ otherwise.

**What I've tried**

I've tried counting the number of even and odd occurrences of $a_j \cdot Y$ but am struggling to find the right expression. It's easy to say something like "since $a_j$ enumerate the non-zero elements of the unit cube, by symmetry: the number of even values of $a_j \cdot Y$ will always be less than the number of odd values of $a_j \cdot Y$." but arguments by symmetry are easy to get wrong. I'd prefer a more explicit characterization.

Comment: You say that $Y$ is drawn uniformly at random from the cube but then it sounds like you're asked to evaluate the sum for every possible value of $Y$ (not just e.g. its expected value or anything like that). So what's the significance of the "uniformly at random" part of the problem? Is this a multi-part problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier if you remove the artificial condition that you only consider the nonzero elements of $\{ 0, 1 \}^m$ and just consider all of them. Then it's clear that if $Y = 0$ the sum is $2^m$ since every term is equal to $1$, and if $Y \neq 0$ then we really can can argue by symmetry: $Y$ must have some nonzero bit $i$, and then flipping the $i^{th}$ bit of $a$ is a bijection from the $+1$ terms to the $-1$ terms, so they cancel out exactly and the sum is $0$. Now subtract the term corresponding to $a = 0$ to conclude.

More formally, I invite you to check that if $Y$ has $k$ nonzero bits and $m-k$ zero bits then this sum (again, with the $a = 0$ term added in) can be factored as $(1 - 1)^k (1 + 1)^{m-k}$.

Comment: Thanks, the first part was easy for me to follow. The second was a challenge for me but I think I eventually got it: $\sum_j^{2^n} (-1)^{\langle a_j, Y\rangle} = \sum_j^{2^n} (-1)^{\langle a_j, Y\rangle}(1)^{\langle 1-a_j, Y\rangle}$  notice that the exponents sum to $k$. By the expansion of $(x + y)^l$, this sum is $(1-1)^k$. Although I dont get the second factor in your expression, I think it comes from a similar argument or step I am missing.

Comment: @MONODA43: it may be easier to instead consider $(1 - x)^k (1 + x)^{m-k}$ and then substitute $x = 1$. The $(1 - x)$ factors correspond to the $k$ nonzero bits of $Y$ and the $(1 + x)$ factors correspond to the $m-k$ nonzero bits of $Y$.

Comment: Great thanks, that's much clearer.